# display data from database of an HTML form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am trying to display results from my database using PHP through an HTML form. Once the user clicks the submit button, based on what they enter in each field, results should be shown accordingly.

E.g. if I click on "Rooms" in my drop down menu, and when I specify a certain price in the text field for price and for the rest of the fields, anything related to what I searched should be displayed.

I was able to do it for the drop down menu, but I don't know how I can enter multiple values and when I click submit it generates the data accordingly.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="dropdown2.php" method="POST">
        <select name="testing" type="text">
            <option value="Choose">Choose type of stay</option>
            <option value="Flat">Flat</option>
            <option value="Room">Room</option>
            <option value="Apartment">Apartment</option>
            <option value="Villa">Villa</option>
        </select>
        <p></p>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="14%" class="label">Minimum Price MYR</td>
            <td width="42%"><input type="text" name="textfield4" id="textfield4" class="text" /></td>
            <td class="label">Maximum Price MYR</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2" class="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Bed Rooms</td>
            <td>
                <label>
                <input type="text" name="search" id="textfield5" class="text smalltextarea" />
                </label>
            </td>
            <td class="label">Bathrooms</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="textfield3" id="textfield3" class="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <p></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());
    if(isset($_POST['testing'])){
    $query = $_POST['testing']; 

    $min_length = 3;

    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 
        $query = htmlspecialchars($query);          
        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rooms
            WHERE (`name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`price` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`description` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 

        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
            echo "<p><h3>".$results['name']."</h3>"."RM " .$results['price']."</p>"."<p>".$results['description']."</p>";
        }

    }
    else{ 
        echo "No results";
    }
        }
        else{ 
            echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm new to PHP and MySQL... any help is appreciated!

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of PHP v5.5 and have been removed as of v7.0. They should not be used for new code and should be swapped out for [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) equivalents as soon as possible.

Comment: `<select name="testing" type="text">` - *Busted*.

Comment: ...`<select>` does not have a type.

Comment: You need to generate the query dynamically. You should upgrade your driver and use parameterized queries. When storing the data did you use `htmlspecialchars`?

Comment: nice spot @Fred-ii-

Comment: You're also not using any (other) $_POST's for the select/inputs. That type in `<select>` failed you here, as I already stated.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for pointing that one out. I've changed all `mysql` functions to `mysqli`. But I still don't understand what you mean by "not using (other) $_POST's for the select/inputs"

Answer (score 0):

first id say change the names to something a bit more reconcilable
also you are missing a name or description field not sure which one (since the names don't resemble the database fields)

replace mysql for pdo or mysqli i used pdo in this example 
since if you upgrade to php 7 mysql functions are removed (like suggested in the comments above)

instead of the mysql real escape etc you can use a prepared statement

also what you were missing in the query were the other post fields like suggested in the comments for example how many bathrooms, the minprice, the maxprice etc (these fields are posted by the user but not used in the query)
you were using the same postfield for all of those values in your query

now based on your fields i am assuming for example if someone fills in minprice = 12 and descr = flat that the result both has to have a minimum price of 12 and a description like flat so you need to change the OR's you used in your query for AND's based on which field are filled in

here is a bit of an example on how to go about it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <select name="description" type="text">
            <option value="Choose">Choose type of stay</option>
            <option value="Flat">Flat</option>
            <option value="Room">Room</option>
            <option value="Apartment">Apartment</option>
            <option value="Villa">Villa</option>
        </select>
        <p></p>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="14%" class="label">Minimum Price MYR</td>
            <td width="42%"><input type="text" name="minprice" id="textfield4" class="text" /></td>
            <td class="label">Maximum Price MYR</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="maxprice" id="textfield2" class="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Bed Rooms</td>
            <td>
                <label>
                <input type="text" name="bedrooms" id="textfield5" class="text smalltextarea" />
                </label>
            </td>
            <td class="label">Bathrooms</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="bathrooms" id="textfield3" class="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <p></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    <?php

        $minDescriptionLength = 3;
        if(isset($_POST['description'])) {
            $descr = $_POST['description'];

            if(strlen($descr) >= $minDescriptionLength) {
                $connectionConfigArr = array('host' => 'localhost', 'dbname' => 'test', 'user' => 'root', 'password' => '');
                // here we are making the database connection, 
                // first param = connection string, second param = user, third param = password
                $dbh = new PDO(
                    'mysql:host=' . $connectionConfigArr['host'] . ';dbname=' . $connectionConfigArr['dbname'], 
                    $connectionConfigArr['user'], 
                    $connectionConfigArr['password']
                );


                $bindParamArr = array();

                //since we check this one in the start i assumed it's required so we can use it in the base for the query
                $query = 'SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE `description` LIKE :descr ';

                //here for each extra field that is filled in we basicaly are going to add it to the query string
                //and we push the value to the bindParamArray which will after we added the query add the values safely to the query
                if(isset($_POST['minprice']) && $_POST['minprice']) {
                    $query .= 'AND `price` > :minprice ';
                    array_push($bindParamArr, array('field' => ':minprice', 'value' => $_POST['minprice'], 'type' => PDO::PARAM_INT));
                }
                if(isset($_POST['maxprice']) && $_POST['maxprice']) {
                    $query .= 'AND `price` < :maxprice ';
                    array_push($bindParamArr, array('field' => ':maxprice', 'value' => $_POST['maxprice'], 'type' => PDO::PARAM_INT));
                }
                if(isset($_POST['bathrooms']) && $_POST['bathrooms']) {
                    $query .= 'AND `bathrooms` = :bathrooms ';
                    array_push($bindParamArr, array('field' => ':bathrooms', 'value' => $_POST['bathrooms'], 'type' => PDO::PARAM_INT));
                }
                if(isset($_POST['bedrooms']) && $_POST['bedrooms']) {
                    $query .= 'AND `bedrooms` = :bedrooms ';
                    array_push($bindParamArr, array('field' => ':bedrooms', 'value' => $_POST['bedrooms'], 'type' => PDO::PARAM_INT));
                }

                //we still need to push the description to the array
                array_push($bindParamArr, array('field' => ':descr', 'value' => '%' . $descr . '%', 'type' => PDO::PARAM_STR));


                //here we prepare the query
                $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

                //here we bind the params safely
                foreach($bindParamArr as $bParam) {
                    $stmt->bindParam($bParam['field'], $bParam['value'], $bParam['type']);
                }

                $stmt->execute();

                //use this to get the amount of rows the query returned
                $rowCount = $stmt->rowCount();

                if($rowCount > 0) {
                    //we loop through the stmt fetch function which will iterate through the resultset
                    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        echo "<p><h3>".$row['name']."</h3>"."RM " .$row['price']."</p>"."<p>".$row['description']."</p>";
                    }
                }
                else { 
                    echo "No results";
                }
            }
            else { 
                echo "Minimum length is ".$minDescriptionLength;
            }
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```